# Matplotlib Specgram logarithm y-scale axis is not functioning

Tags: python, matplotlib, spectrogram

Based off previous stack overflow questions, I know what needs to be done is `plt.yscale('log', nonposy = 'clip')`or `ax.set_yscale('log')` However, this is resulting in a blank/empty plot. There was also a page that said this functionality does not exist- however, this was 6 years ago, and updates have happened since then.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ha = plt.subplot('111')
Pxx, freqs, bins, im = plt.specgram((tempdf[j]), NFFT=NFFT, noverlap = NOVERLAP, pad_to=PADTO, Fs=Fs)#, , mode='magnitude')
#plt.yscale('log')
#ax.set_yscale('log')
#plt.yscale('log', nonposy='clip')            
plt.show()
```